# Solve command terminated with exit code 137 in pod Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm running Kubernetes service using exec which have few pods in statefulset. 
If I kill one of the master pod used by service in exec, it exits with code 137. I want to forward it to another pod immediately after killing or apply wait before exiting. I need help. Waiting for answer. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more detail and state the steps you have taken.

Comment: Post some examples of what you want to achieve. Are you using service for this pods?

Answer (score 18):

137 means your process exited due to SIGKILL, usually because the system ran out of RAM. Unfortunately no delay is possible with SIGKILL, the kernel just drops your process and that is that. Kubernetes does detect it rapidly and if you're using a Service-based network path it will usually react in 1-2 seconds. I would recommend looking into why your process is being hard-killed and fixing that :)

Comment: Failing health checks will also produce a status code 137.

Comment: Only if your process does not respond to SIGTERM within the configured time limit, I think the default is 10 seconds.